# Ramsey Theory//Question of Notation

Tags: notation, ramsey-theory

**I RESOLVED THIS QUESTION FOR MYSELF, THANKS FOR VIEWING, SORRY**
We have this notation:
$$
\mathcal A \to \mathcal B_k^{n}
$$
Which means:
\begin{align*}
&(\forall A \in \mathcal A)(\forall f)\left(f:[A]^{n}\to \{1,2,\dots,k\}\Longrightarrow \\(\exists B\subseteq A)(\exists i \in \{1,\dots,k\})(B\in \mathcal B \land f \text{ has value $i$ on } [B]^{n})\right)
\end{align*}
To me this is saying for every set from the family $\mathcal A$, for every function from the set of all partitions of $A$ with length $n$ into $\{1,2,\dots, k\}$ there is a subset of $A$, namely $B$ such that $B$ has constant value $i$ on every partition of length $n$ of it and $B$ is a member of $\mathcal B$. Am I interpreting this notation correctly? Is this saying that there is a definitive member $B \in \mathcal B$ that can be colored $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$$\dots$ or $k$ given that we partition it into $n$ many pieces and it is some subset of $A\in \mathcal A$? 
I'm assuming that:
$[A]^n$ mean the set of all partitions of $A$ with cardinality $n$. Am I correct in this interpretation?

**I RESOLVED THIS QUESTION FOR MYSELF, THANKS FOR VIEWING, SORRY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRONG $[X]^{n}$ in this context means the set of all size $n$ subsets of $X$. 
 E.G. 
$$
6\to3_2^{2}
$$

means for every set of cardinality $6$, for all functions from $f:[6]^{2}\to \{1,2\}$ there exists a $B\subset 6$, such that $[B]^2$ has constant color and $B\subset 3$.

Comment: Rustyn, typically the notation has parenthesis around the $3$, as in $6\to(3)^2_2$, as you may want to vary the goal depending on the target: $9\to(3,4)^2$. There are also generalizations to other contexts, where (for example) rather than just numbers we color $n$-element subsets of certain structures, and require that there is a certain substructure all of whose $n$-element subsets are monochromatic. And there are yet other extensions. For several examples of this, you may want to see the book **Mathematics of Ramsey theory** by Nešetřil and Rödl.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I am really starting to enjoy ramsey theory as i digest more. For example, $\Omega \to \Omega_{k}^{1}$ is a satisfying partition relation. It says that we can partition an omega cover of space X into as many finitely pieces as we want and one of those pieces will again be an omega cover. I find this property to be amazing.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I might check out that book when I have time.